# Why is the trapezoidal rule more accurate when either the initial or the last value is close to 0?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am working on a project and I can't grasp why is this the case:[image: Reference]

Is it because the only one bound of the integral is taken into account?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not true in general.  Note that the (absolute) error in the trapezoid rule for $\int_a^b f(x)\; dx$ is exactly the same as that for $\int_a^b (f(x)  - f(a))\; dx$ or $\int_a^b (f(x) - f(b))\; dx$, where the integrand is $0$ at one endpoint or the other.  Or, for that matter,
$$\int_a^b \left(f(x) - f(a) - \frac{x-a}{b-a} (f(b)-f(a))\right)\; dx$$
where it is $0$ at both ends.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) Helped me to get my head around these integrals.